# Discord bot Task.Delay() does not work parallel

Tags: c#, .net-core, discord

I have an issue creating discord bot, async is something new for me. The problem is that this Task.Delay() delays entire program, not a single method. I mean if you will spam 5 messages, it will be working with the first, then delay for 10 seconds until it will start working with the second message. I want to make it parallel. Task.Delay() works for me as Thread.Sleep(). Both have the same effect.

Someone writes a message containing no attachments in a specific channel, so if bot sees it the message will be redirected to another channel. I want to delete person's message, write bot reply to user and wait for 10 seconds before the bot's answer will be deleted. Now it works like a user writes message, bot deletes it and stops entire program for 10 seconds, not task. So I can spam, for example, 10 messages and a bot will delete them after 100 seconds, because program is delayed

````
using Discord;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord.Commands;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace BillyNet
{
    class Program
    {
        DiscordSocketClient discord;
        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        public async Task RunBotAsync()
        {
            discord = new DiscordSocketClient();
            string token = "token here";

            discord.Log += Log;
            discord.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;

            await discord.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await discord.StartAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private async Task MessageReceived(SocketMessage message)
        {
            var chat = discord.GetChannel(466671032783077389) as IMessageChannel;
            var redirectChat = discord.GetChannel(458517175536320514) as IMessageChannel;

            if ((message.Attachments.Count < 1) && (message.Channel.Id == chat.Id) && (!message.Author.IsBot))
            {
                var botReply = await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Ваше сообщение было переправлено в канал {MentionUtils.MentionChannel(redirectChat.Id)}." +
                        $"\nВ {MentionUtils.MentionChannel(chat.Id)} запрещены сообщения не содержащие фотографии.");
                await redirectChat.SendMessageAsync($"**[{message.Author.Username}]**: {message.Content}" +
                    $"\n\nСообщение переадресованно из {MentionUtils.MentionChannel(chat.Id)}.");

                await message.DeleteAsync();
                await Task.Delay(10000);
                await botReply.DeleteAsync();
            }
        }

        private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Tasks != multi-threading.  Asynchronous != multi-threaded. Why do you expect any kind of parallelism here? Do you know how `DiscordSocketClient` is implemented? Maybe it processes several messages sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to launch message processing with **Task.Run** method, it will run your function async. Change your MessageReceived method like this.

```
public async Task MessageReceived(SocketMessage message)
    {
        var messageHandleTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var chat = discord.GetChannel(466671032783077389) as IMessageChannel;
            var redirectChat = discord.GetChannel(458517175536320514) as IMessageChannel;

            if ((message.Attachments.Count < 1) && (message.Channel.Id == chat.Id) && (!message.Author.IsBot))
            {
                var botReply = await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Ваше сообщение было переправлено в канал {MentionUtils.MentionChannel(redirectChat.Id)}." +
                        $"\nВ {MentionUtils.MentionChannel(chat.Id)} запрещены сообщения не содержащие фотографии.");
                await redirectChat.SendMessageAsync($"**[{message.Author.Username}]**: {message.Content}" +
                    $"\n\nСообщение переадресованно из {MentionUtils.MentionChannel(chat.Id)}.");

                await message.DeleteAsync();
                await Task.Delay(10000);
                await botReply.DeleteAsync();
            }
        });
    }
```

**Edit 1:** changed new thread instantiation to **Task.Run** method.

Comment: @НадильКаримов, it's a very bad idea to mix async code with explicit threading. If one wants to offload task to a thread pool thread, there is `Task.Run` API.

Comment: @НадильКаримор, I think ```messageHandleTask``` variable does not make any sense nomore